# Why i can't screenshot circularprogress in flutter (widget testing)

Tags: flutter

```
class MockNewService extends Mock implements NewsService {}

void main() {

  late MockNewService mockNewService;

  setUp(() {
    mockNewService = MockNewService();
  });

  final articlesFromService = [
    Article(title: 'Test 1', content: 'Test 1 content'),
    Article(title: 'Test 1', content: 'Test 1 content'),
    Article(title: 'Test 1', content: 'Test 1 content'),
  ];


  void arrangeNewsServiceReturn3ArticlesAfter3sec() {
    when(() => mockNewService.getArticlesApi()).thenAnswer((invocation) async {
      await Future.delayed(const Duration(seconds: 5));
      return articlesFromService;
    });
  }

  Widget createWidgetUnderTest() {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'News App',
      home: ChangeNotifierProvider(
        create: (_) => NewsChangeNotifier(mockNewService),
        child: const NewsPage(),
      ),
    );
  }

  testGoldens("Loading indecator is displayed while waiting for article",
      (WidgetTester tester) async {
    arrangeNewsServiceReturn3ArticlesAfter3sec();
    await tester.pumpWidgetBuilder(createWidgetUnderTest(), surfaceSize: Device.iphone11.size);
    await tester.pump(const Duration(milliseconds: 500));

   ** // This is Error:   Test failed. See exception logs above.
  The test description was: Loading indecator is displayed while waiting for article**
    await screenMatchesGolden(
      tester,
      'circle_displayed',
      // finder:find.byElementType(CircularProgressIndicator),
      autoHeight: true,
    );


   **  // This is working and can found progress-indicator**
    // expect(find.byKey(const Key('progress-indicator')), findsOneWidget);

    await tester.pumpAndSettle();
  });

}
```

This is my service for demo my project which in test I use mock package instead for mockpu article.

```
import 'package:flutter_lorem/flutter_lorem.dart';
import 'package:flutter_testing_tutorial/article.dart';

/// A News service simulating communication with a server.
class NewsService {
  // Simulating a remote database
  final _articles = List.generate(
    10,
    (_) => Article(
      title: lorem(paragraphs: 1, words: 3),
      content: lorem(paragraphs: 10, words: 500),
    ),
  );

  Future<List<Article>> getArticlesApi() async {
    await Future.delayed(const Duration(seconds: 1));
    return _articles;
  }
}
```

This is my provider to my page.

```
class NewsChangeNotifier extends ChangeNotifier {
  final NewsService _newsService;

  NewsChangeNotifier(this._newsService);

  List<Article> _articles = [];

  List<Article> get articles => _articles;

  bool _isLoading = false;
  bool get isLoading => _isLoading;

  Future<void> getArticles() async {
    _isLoading = true;
    notifyListeners();
    _articles = await _newsService.getArticlesApi();
    _isLoading = false;
    notifyListeners();
  }
}
```

This is my page

```
class NewsPage extends StatefulWidget {
  const NewsPage({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<NewsPage> createState() => _NewsPageState();
}

class _NewsPageState extends State<NewsPage> {
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    Future.microtask(
      () => context.read<NewsChangeNotifier>().getArticles(),
    );
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: const Text('News'),
      ),
      body: Consumer<NewsChangeNotifier>(
        builder: (context, notifier, child) {
          if (notifier.isLoading) {
            return const Center(
              child: CircularProgressIndicator(
                key: Key('progress-indicator'),
              ),
            );
          }
          return ListView.builder(
            itemCount: notifier.articles.length,
            itemBuilder: (_, index) {
              final article = notifier.articles[index];
              return Card(
                elevation: 2,
                child: InkWell(
                  onTap: () {
                    Navigator.of(context).push(
                      MaterialPageRoute(
                        builder: (_) => ArticlePage(article: article),
                      ),
                    );
                  },
                  child: ListTile(
                    title: Text(article.title),
                    subtitle: Text(
                      article.content,
                      maxLines: 4,
                      overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              );
            },
            padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(
              horizontal: 8,
              vertical: 16,
            ),
          );
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

I can use  follow this code,without  finder:find.byElementType(CircularProgressIndicator)`` but i can't found CircularProgressIndicator on my image output.

```
await screenMatchesGolden(
      tester,
      'circle_displayed',
      autoHeight: true,
    );
```

How i can screenshot circularprogress ??